# Question Related to Custom control

Tags: iphone

I need ur help for making custom control in my project
Is Custom Control is Possible in Iphone?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: please can you throw some more lights...?

Comment: I have value of variabel int tag.
now  when value of variabel tag is x ,
I need x numbers of UITextView.
and UITextView  arrange such that after certain distance which is common beetween 2 UITextView should be maintain for all UITextView
and if i'm typing on 1 UITextView as the size OF 1st UITextView increase all UITextView below this UITextView goes down
properly and resize automatically

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to make custom controls for iPhone applications.